# Flutter and Flame, how to keep FlameGame widget alive?

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

Working on a game project where:
I have a BottomNavigationBar navigating betwen my custom Widgets where one of them is a FlameGame. I don't want to unload and reload the widgets when player navigates as it will be frequent and expensive.

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGe45NikVqE) and now my custom Widgets are being preserved, except for the FlameGame.

Tried adding AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin. Wanted me to implement 12 overrides... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapped my GameWidget in another custom widget of mine that implements the KeepAlive mixin.

It works now.